# Redis not deleting key after rename

Tags: redis

Once in a while my Redis is not deleting the source key after rename. I am using Redis version 7 in a cluster mode setup. I noticed this happened several times in the last one month and this seems to happen while renaming big hash keys. Appreciate if anyone has thoughts on the root cause.

I am unable to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you keep calling hash commands with the old key name after calling `RENAME`? Such commands may create a new key with the old name.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I will investigate this and report back if this was the case.